# GLADE & Pygtk: how to split dynamically windows?

Tags: python-3.x, pygtk, glade

I made a GLADE file, a main window of type "GtkNotebook" and there are several pages in it (Window1 = Page1, Page2, Page3, Page4).

a) Is it possible, like a web-browser, to take one of this page and separate it from the main windows? Example Page4 taken away with the cursor would create a Windows2

b) If not (I could not achieve it till now), I will have probably to create 2 windows which open automatically when I start my application (one will be Window1 = Page1, Page2, Page3, the second one will be Window2 with Page4). I will search how to do this after I have a feedback from here if a) could be done in any way.

Thanks (this is my first post here)

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not posible to do dinamically.

As you know on Pygtk we load the glade file by this way `wTree = gtk.glade.XML("localize.glade")` only once time, and after that we have on scope the access to all tree of controls and componets.

If you have a window loaded, you can load another window, but not pull apart a tab that belong to a window loaded already, is something that not insted on pygtk, is not supported. Each window run on a singular process, i can not figure out how to pull apart it from the root proccess.

I hope its helps you out.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I will now create a button in the main windows:
"Detach the page" "Yes/not". With the answer "yes", it will open a new windows exactly the same than the "page4".

Comment: Considering the python 3 tag was used, I'm gussing they meant PyGObject not pygtk.